# Can't use mergeMap on a FirebaseListObservable?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

Went I try to use mergeMap on a FirebaseListObservable I get the following error :

```
ERROR TypeError: chats.mergeMap is not a function
    at MapSubscriber.project (tabs.ts:93)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at Notification.observe (Notification.js:32)
    at QueueAction.ObserveOnSubscriber.dispatch (observeOn.js:50)
    at QueueAction.AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:111)
    at QueueAction.execute (QueueAction.js:33)
    at QueueScheduler.AsyncScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.js:36)
    at QueueAction.schedule (QueueAction.js:27)
    at QueueScheduler.Scheduler.schedule (Scheduler.js:43)
```

Here is my component code:

```
this.msgService.getUserChatList()
          .mergeMap( chats => chats.mergeMap( chat => {
                return this.msgService.getLastMessage(chat.$key)
                  .map( lastMess => {
                    console.log('lastMess ', lastMess);
                    return this.containsUnreadMessages(lastMess, chat.lastPresence);
                  });
                } )
          )
          .last()
          .subscribe( (results) => {
            console.log('finished ', results)
            // Set global unread var
            this.unread = this.anyUnread;
          } );
```

The getUserChatList fonction that returns a FirebaseListObservable:

```
getUserChatList(currentUserUid?: string): any {
    let company = this.authService.getCurrentUserCompany();
    let uid;
    currentUserUid ? uid = currentUserUid : uid = this.authService.getCurrentUserUid();
    let path = `/${company}/users/${uid}/chats`;
    return this.af.list(path);
  }
```

It looks like we have to double wrap the FirebaseListObservable [Github feature request](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/848)

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: Did you include the operator with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';`?

Comment: I had imported the all Observable library import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'. But I tried to add your import too but the error remains...

Comment: `chats` is not an observable, so you cannot call `mergeMap` on it. It's an array.

Comment: Are you sure `this.af.list(path)` returns an Observable?

Comment: @CozyAzure it returns a FirebaseListObservable https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md Plus, I tried a simpler version of my code where I just subscribed to it directly.

Comment: @cartant That's where I get confused... map works but mapMerge don't. Anyway I would expect chats to be an array of Observables. How could I achieve what I want to do here? That is to say, properly iterate through each item and wait for all iteration to be completed and then update this.unread